# Regex allow dates and zeroes only

Tags: regex

In my current regex how can i allow dates and zeores like `00000000`?

i have tried this pattern: `^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(19|20)\d{2}$` but its only matching dates like `10122016`

Comment: Like this - `^(((3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(19|20)\d{2})|(00000000))$`?

Comment: `^(\d{0,31})((0|1)\d{2})((19|20)\d{2})|0+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a pattern for all zeros in there. Perhaps something like this instead:

```
^((3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(19|20)\d{2}|0+)$
```

Note the `|0+` towards the end. If you need specifically eight zeroes, then:

```
^((3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(19|20)\d{2}|0{8})$
```

Comment: hi what might be the pattern to match undetermined zeroes also?

Comment: @Nevi The first pattern I provided matches either an eight digit date or a series of one or more zeroes.